# Is it possible to do reusable snippets within AngularJS templates?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm finding myself repeating the same snippets of code again and again, is it possible to do something like this in AngularJS:

```
<div ng-snippet="mySnippet"> 
  This is a snippet 
</div> 

<div ng-snippet="anotherSnippet"> 
  Yet another snippet!!
</div>

<ng:include src="anotherSnippet">
<ng:include src="anotherSnippet">
<ng:include src="mySnippet">
```

and the output of the above would be:

```
Yet another snippet!!
Yet another snippet!!
This is a snippet
```

I'm not necessarily looking for this exact "ng:include" solution or pattern but something that would reduce the repetition in my templates.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

```
<script type='text/ng-template' id="mySnippet"> 
    This is a snippet 
</script> 

<script type='text/ng-template' id="anotherSnippet"> 
    Yet another snippet!!
</script>

<ng-include src="'anotherSnippet'"></ng-include>
<ng-include src="'anotherSnippet'"></ng-include>
<ng-include src="'mySnippet'"></ng-include>
```

This should be what you want.

Docs for [script](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3ascript) and [ng-include](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angInclude).

Comment: Awesome. What about a form where you want inputs to link to different objects, and different names for the inputs? https://plnkr.co/edit/iCOIq88e7gSSYaE92b0t?p=preview

Answer (score 12):

This sounds like you want to use [directives](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive). Here is a simple example: http://jsfiddle.net/gyF6V/1/

Comment: I'd go with directives over includes; they'll make your markup more readable.

Comment: Whenever I see html inside a string, something inside me just doesn't feel right.

Comment: If you don't want html inside the the javascript, just use the `templateUrl` property instead of `template` and point it to the html file that has your template.