# reusable templates/markup in angularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am working on a project using angularJS, however I'm a bit unsure of the best way to approach this in the framework.

I have an endpoint that makes a request and searches for some data using some parameters, and upon success, it will loop through the table and return matching items.

For each item I make an HTTP call to get some data and the success response would create the scope that would be used in the markup.

How can I reuse the same HTML in the loop AND set/re-set the scope each time so the markup gets generated for each item...or perhaps theres a better 'angular specific' approach.. Thanks

**HTML** (this is the markup i would like to reuse)

```
<div class="carouselWrapperOuter">
  <div class="carouselWrapper">
    <ul rn-carousel rn-carousel-controls rn-carousel-duration="300" class="image carouselholder">
      <li ng-repeat="stuff in homeData" class="square" data-url="{{stuff.id}}" ng-click="trackOpen()">
        <div class="squareThumb">
          <img ng-src="{{stuff.artwork_url}}">
        </div>
        <div class="itemTitle">{{stuff.title}}</div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS

```js
 angAppFactory.getUser({
   where: {
    endpointname: "sourcename",
    username: "user123"
   }
  }).success(function(success) {
  console.log(success)

  //returns a couple of results which would make the following request AND use the markup/set the scope for each item

  for (var i = 0; i < success.results.length; i++) {

    var endpointid = success.results[i].sourceid
    $http({
      method: 'GET',
      url: 'http://someurl.com'
    }).success(function(data) {
      //console.log(data)
      //scope being set

      $scope.homeData = data;

    }).error(function() {
      alert("error");
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: You can create Directive which can be reused as many time as you want

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12698796/is-it-possible-to-do-reusable-snippets-within-angular-templates

Comment: Thanks I will check this out and keep you posted on my progress