# Reusable forms in angular

Tags: angularjs

So I have a form that's basically the same in many different instances, except the names of the inputs may vary, and the data the form represents will be different.

I got a good start on reusable snippets from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12698796/is-it-possible-to-do-reusable-snippets-within-angular-templates), but I want to expand on that, and figure out how to make it more dynamic.

**HTML**

```
<script type='text/ng-template' id="mySnippet"> 
  <form>
    {{mySinppet.firstThing}}<input id="first-input"/>
    {{mySinppet.secondThing}}<input id="second-input"/>
  </form>
</script>
  
<ng-include src="'mySnippet'" ng-model="thingOne"></ng-include>
<ng-include src="'mySnippet'" ng-model="thingTwo"></ng-include>
```

**JS**

```
$scope.thingOne={
  firstThing: "1",
  secondThing: "2",
  foo: src["first-input"],
  bar: src["second-input"],
};
$scope.thingTwo={
  firstThing: "3",
  secondThing: "4",
  first: src["first-input"],
  second: src["second-input"],
};
```

Here's the plunker for this code (which obviously doesn't work): https://plnkr.co/edit/iCOIq88e7gSSYaE92b0t?p=preview

So how do I set up the snippet/ng-includes to allow communication with a model?

Comment: It's time to consider a directive.

Comment: You may try angular-formly (http://angular-formly.com/#/) for building dynamic forms. Your HTML remains unchanged, only form data in JSON format is changed

Comment: @Makoto can you expand on that? Possibly post an answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer you linked to is 4 years old. Nobody codes like this anymore.
The unaccepted answer though hints at the better solution.

```
<reusable-form ng-model="thingOne"></reusable-form>
<reusable-form ng-model="thingTwo"></reusable-form>
```

However there's a limit to how dynamic/reusable you can make a form.

The model you bound to your form should have the same properties.

```
$scope.thingOne={
  firstThing: "1",
  secondThing: "2"
};
$scope.thingTwo={
  firstThing: "3",
  secondThing: "4"
};
```

So that the directive is generic enough to be reusable:

```
  .directive('reusableForm', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: {
        ngModel: '='
      },
      template: `
        <input id="first-input" type="text" ng-model="ngModel.firstThing" />
        <input id="second-input" type="text" ng-model="ngModel.secondThing" />
      `
    }
  });
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/3vrDkrBkA5u6w4hQiW78?p=preview

If you want to make it more dynamic than this, you will end up with spaghetti code and fight with a [scope mess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38821980/how-to-write-directive-on-class-in-angular-js/38823610#38823610).

Comment: Awesome! Thanks so much. Would you also mind adding the HTML to implement the directive?

Comment: @TravisHeeter how do you mean? You have everything in the plunker.

Comment: Ah, didn't notice the plunker link.